# Is there `addObject`'s passive method?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

There're two mutable arrays, according some statement control flow to make object be added to different mutable array. I know I could use `[theMutableArray addObject: anyObject]` but a little bit verbose I think. What I really need is `[object addTo: (statement ? theMutableArrayA : theMutableArrayB)]`.

So, Is there any `addObject`'s passive method?

Comment: I think the reverse of `addObject` should be `removeObject`. :)

Comment: @KudoCC I just update my statement :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think you really need a passive method, because you can use an expression which returns an object instead of a `receiver`.

```
NSMutableArray *m ;
NSMutableArray *n ;
id o ;
[(1?m:n) addObject:o] ;
```

Comment: Good switch for your method.